# Python TypeError: not enough arguments for format string in case of string %s

Tags: python, html, string, typeerror

```
wrapper = """<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table style="height: 100px;" width="500">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3"><a id="imgrec1" href="http://www.w3.org"><img src="%s" alt="Smiley face" width="50" height="100" /><br /><br /></a></td>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3"><a id="imgrec1" href="http://www.w3.org"><img src="%s" alt="Smiley face" width="50" height="100" /><br /><br /></a></td>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>"""

str=""
for i in reclist[:2]: 
    str=str + "I[\"" + i + "\"]," + "T[\"" + i + "\"]," +"R[\"" + i + "\"]," +"P[\"" + i + "\"]," 
str = str[:-1]
print str
whole = wrapper % (str)

Output: I["M1"],T["M1"],R["M1"],P["M1"],I["M2"],T["M2"],R["M2"],P["M2"]
    whole = wrapper % (str)
    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

As `wrapper` has exactly 8 %s and `str` has also 8 tuples, but still showing error `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string.`

But instead of str, if I use

```
    whole = wrapper %  
(I["M1"],T["M1"],R["M1"],P["M1"],I["M2"],T["M2"],R["M2"],P["M2"])
```

then it is working fine.

I refer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252358/typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string-when-using-s) [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146190/python-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string) for this problem, but it did not help.

Comment: Please post a simple `wrapper = "..."; str = ...; output = wrapper % str` example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you get an error because you pass a string as a single argument when formatting a string.
You can create a list initially:

```
str = []
for i in reclist[:2]:
    str += [I[i], T[i] etc.]
```

and then use:

```
whole = wrapper % tuple(str)
```

so that every item in a list will be passed as a separate argument.

Comment: Thanks. Output of this program is now  ['I', '[', '"', 'M', '"', ']', ',', 'T', '[', '"', 'M', etc.]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    whole = wrapper % tuple(str)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: What are the I, T, R, P variables? Are they dictionaries?

Comment: Try to create list with no quotes around them. `[I[i], T[i]]` instead of `['I','[', i , ']', 'T', '[', i, ']']` or something like this.

Comment: Yes. I,R,T,P are dictionaries.

Comment: I don't know then. Could you post the for loop again? Probably you create a list with more arguments than needed.